# Linearize equation

Tags: calculus

I have the following equation. I need to write it in a linear form $y=mx$.

> $$M(x) = N \left(3-\exp\left(-\frac{x}{c}\right)\right)$$

Here, $M$ is the dependent variable and $x$ is the independent variable.  $N$ is a constant. My attempt so far:

$$\ln(M) = \ln (N ) + \ln(3 - \exp(-\frac{x}{c}) )$$

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: @Laufen Hi, I tried this method.

Comment: ln(M) = ln (N ) + ln(3 - exp(-x/c) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can rewrite your function as

$$\frac{M-3N}{N}=e^{-x/c}$$

that is

$$L=e^{-x/c}$$

Than take the log on both sides getting

$$\log L=-\frac{x}{c}$$

that is

$$y=-\frac{1}{c}\cdot x$$

...as you desired

Comment: your answer is really helpful.